# How to group by factor Correlation Statistics with DPLYR in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to extract the result of a `cor.test` (I mean purposedly :  $estimate   and   $ p.value), grouped by a factor.  The dataframe used is of this kind :

```
  'data.frame': 8940 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Code   : Factor w/ 864 levels "420639","427354",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ TxP    : num  0.0107 0.0107 0.0107 0.0239 0.0239 ...
$ Vol    : num  63193 59854 43229 38486 37028 ...
```

Using `dplyr` package, the code I wrote was :

```
‘CorResult <- function(data, x, y, Grped){
  x <- x
  y <- y
  fac <- as.name(as.character(Grped)[2])
  corR <- interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="pearson",na.action = "na.exclude")$estimate, x = x, y = y)
  Pval <- interp(~ cor.test(x, y,method="pearson",na.action = "na.exclude")$p.value, x = x, y = y)
  summarise_( group_by_(data, fac), R=corR, Pval=Pval)
  }
CorResult  (data = data4, data4$Vol, data4$TxP, Grped= ~Code )
```

The result I receive is always the same values, whatever the Groupe by !

```
'# A tibble: 864 x 3
   Code        R                             pval
   <fct>   <dbl>                            <dbl>
 1 420639  0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
 2 427354  0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
 3 429885  0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
 4 1625921 0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
 5 1625922 0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
 6 1631209 0.117 0.000000000000000000000000000134
# ... with 854 more rows
```

Where did I do wrong ? I missed something. Any hand would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome. Can you please post dput(head(data))?